# SharePoint List Custom Security Features

Tags: list, security, customization

Is there a way to customize security features based on who created a list item?

Examples:
Managers should only be able to see those they have requested
Directors should be able to see anyone that falls in one of their Managers groups
HR should be able to see and approve all
OGM should be able to see and approve all

Comment: Not OOTB. Sounds like you'll either want to set item level permissions or organize into folders. Both have their setbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Your Directors example suggests you need to be able define a one-to-many group relationships and then check within these groups to verify if the person accessing a list item has been granted access.  This type of logic is not available by simply "customizing" permissions settings in the user interface.

But if by "customizing" you mean writing code, then yes, a workflow or event receiver could be written to execute more sophisticated logic and change permissions on individual items.